# Difficulty to make function `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` for geodesic equations

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

Since I started learning python library `sympy` and `scipy`, I wondered how to implement the geodesic equation [1] using the function `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` and `sympy` symbols. I was able to implement a symbolic version of Christoffel's symbols calculation for its integration definition. Also, I defined the ode function for integration steps.

I am not able to make the module `scipy.integrate` work properly as on the module example [3]. The library requires some initial value as initial guess. The algorithm should converge to the curve which binds the points, which is traversed with a constant velocity. Neither the initial and final points are the provided not the velocity norm is constant along the curve.

Therefore, I ask for the help of some good fellows help debugging this issue.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solving_the_geodesic_equations

[2] https://github.com/alloyha/experiments/blob/main/data/geodesics/ellipsoid_geodesics.ipynb

[3] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_bvp

Comment: Is your issue the Christoffel symbols?

Comment: No, they are ok. My issue is the function `solve_bvp`. I cannot make it conevrse to a simple non-singular set of equations as geodesic on a paraboloid (cell 19)

Comment: Can you edit your post to include what you've tried and explain why the solution is incorrect?

Comment: Is it better than before?

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: You may have take a vote of trust: clone locally the repository available on [2], install dependencies for 'jupyter', and run the cells.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should have the code included in the post itself. The code should also be as short as possible but still reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am afraid, it is not possible for this use case. I will close, since we arrived to a deadlock

Comment: Anyways, I submitted an issue on scipy, they said me to come back here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19705

Comment: Do you have any example problems for which you can provide an analytical solution as a guess? That may help with debugging. If the solver terminated with that solution, that is evidence that the problem is set up correctly and maybe your issue is that the guess is not close enough. If not, that is a sign that the problem setup needs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this problem as a minimization problem not a differential equation integration.

Here is an example where I compute the geodesic approximation on an ellipsoid based on the piece-wise linear interpolation over equally spaced points in the path.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy

class Ellipsoid:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=1, c=1):
        self.abc = [a,b,c]
    
    def path(self, theta, phi):
        '''
        Path over a paraboloid with phi=0 at the equator, 
        and at the poles +pi/2 and -pi/2
        '''
        h = np.cos(phi)
        a,b,c = self.abc
        return a * h * np.cos(theta), b * h * np.sin(theta), c * np.sin(phi)
    


    def discretized_path_length(self, theta, phi):
        '''
        Get the points from a path and compute the length
        of the piecewise linear interpolation of it
        '''
        return np.sqrt(sum(np.diff(u)**2 for u in self.path(theta, phi))).sum()


    def _discretized_packed_path_length(self, packed_path, p0, p1):
        '''
        Interface to scipy minimization 
        take a packed array with the parametized path, and two extra
        arguments, p0 the initiala point parameters, and p1 the final
        point parameters.
        '''
        theta, phi = np.vstack([[p0], packed_path.reshape(-1, 2), [p1]]).T
        return self.discretized_path_length(theta, phi)
    
    
    def geodesic(self, p1, p2, n, method='least_squares'):
        '''
        Given p1=(theta1, phi1), p2=(theta1, phi2) and a number
        of segments computes the discretized geodesic
        '''
        theta1, phi1 = p1
        theta2, phi2 = p2
        t_theta = np.linspace(theta1, theta2, n+1)
        t_phi = np.linspace(phi1, phi2, n+1)
        t_packed = np.array([t_theta, t_phi]).T
        
        results = minimize(
            fun=self._discretized_packed_path_length,
            x0=t_packed[1:-1].reshape(-1),
            args=(t_packed[0], t_packed[-1]))

        t_packed[1:-1] = results.x.reshape(-1, 2)
        theta, phi = t_packed.T
        return theta, phi
```

To validate the approach we can check the case where the ellipsoid reduces to a sphere and the geodesic length can be easily calculated as the length of the arc connecting two points.

```
def check_geodesic(p0, p1, n):
    ball = Ellipsoid(1,1,1)
    
    theta, phi = zip(p0, p1)
    theta0 = np.linspace(*theta, n+1)
    phi0 = np.linspace(*phi, n+1)
    
    initial_length = ball.discretized_path_length(theta0, phi0)
    theta, phi = ball.geodesic(p0, p1, n, 'minimize')
    m_geodesic_length = ball.discretized_path_length(theta, phi)
    distance = ball.discretized_path_length(*zip(p0, p1))
    arc = 2*np.arcsin(distance/2)
    print(theta[0], phi[0], theta[-1], phi[-1])
    print('Initial path length:', initial_length)
    print('Distance from start to end', distance)
    print('Geodesic length (minimize):', m_geodesic_length)
    print('Length of arc from start to end', arc)
```

A trivial case traveling over the equator

```py
check_geodesic((0, 0), (1, 0), 100)
```

```txt
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
Initial path length: 0.9999958333385416
Distance from start to end 0.9588510772084059
Geodesic length (minimize): 0.9999958333385416
Length of arc from start to end 0.9999999999999999
```

A non-trivial geodesic

```py
check_geodesic((0, 0.5), (1, 0.5), 100)
```

```txt
0.0 0.5 1.0 0.5
Initial path length: 0.8775789053009355
Distance from start to end 0.8414709848078966
Geodesic length (minimize): 0.8685090778499669
Length of arc from start to end 0.8685118212476727
```

Comment: This works. My initial goal is to find the metric tensor and christoffel symbols of an arbitrary smooth surface and then either find the initial value or the boundary value curve.

Comment: The function `check_geodesic` hsa non-existent method `discretized_path_length` though. Also, method `Ellipsoid.path`has swapped coordinates x and y .

Comment: Let us make some benchmarks: from point $(0, 0)$ to $(0, pi2)$ or $(0, -pi/2)$ is pi/2, ok? This would make the code correct from my point of view.

Comment: You should be able to check that with `check_geodesic((0, 0), (1, np.pi/2), 100)`.

Comment: I modified your answer very slightly, but now I am getting error `TypeError: _discretized_path_length() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given` on the 'minimize' statement. Would you know the reason for such? I removed the call `reshape(-1)` since it was weird-looking.

Comment: I also do not know the actual function you use for distance on a sphere

Comment: That comes from analytic geometry, draw a triangle `OAB` connecting the center `O` of the sphere, the initial `A` point and the final point `B`. The entire path is in the same plane as `OAB`, over a circle of radius 1. Use the length `AB` to get the angle `AOB` and that will give the arc, that is also the geodesic.

Comment: I disagree: if I picture correctly, the straight segment is only equal in length to the curved segment if the circular segment rolls along this straight segment and matches on vertices. Otherwise, the circular segment will be greater. Anyhow, your solving procedure seems consistent to me. Thanks for providing an alternative!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour, some points to bear in mind, you are expected to narrow down your question, and give a short piece of code that others can run to reproduce the issue. When an answer (like this) gives a solution you mark it as the answer. Wellcome to the comunity.